# How do I multiply a SparseVector with a scalar in Breeze?

Tags: breeze

The following example tries to multiply a scalar number of type `Double` with a `SparseVector[(Int, Double)]`:

```
val a = SparseVector(10)(3 -> 1.0, 6 -> 2.0, 9 -> 3.0)
val b = 5.0 * a
```

The code fails to compile because

> Error: could not find implicit value for parameter op: breeze.linalg.operators.OpMulMatrix.Impl2[Double,breeze.linalg.SparseVector[(Int, Double)],That]
>     val b = 5.0 * a

It seems that the implicit implementation for such type of multiplication is missing.

However, if we were to do the same thing on a `DenseVector[Double]`, everything is fine:

```
val a = DenseVector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
val b = 5.0 * a
```

Have I missed a package I should import for the sparse case?

Answer (score 1):

Use `:*` for scaling instead of `*`.

`a :* 5.0` or `5.0 *: a`.